# Paypal check if user has already purchased something

Tags: javascript, paypal

Is it anyhow possible to check from a website with paypal js client lib and API's whether a user/customer has already payed for a digital downloadable good?

Is it possible to check whether the user has a valid subscription (which is payed)?

Is it possible to allow a purchase only once and paypal redirects the user back with a notice he already has purchased it?

What I like to achieve:

- If the user has already payed for a document/subscription, he should not need to
  pay a second time but rather directly get the download. My idea, if
  the user previously payed for it, I'd like to replace the paypal pay
  button with a download button.
- The whole check should happen from the Website and not
  server-to-server communication.
- Download must no be secured if not payed. I do know this may NOT be secure and the user may be able to download the document without paying. That is okay, because this is a test whether the user is willing to pay for something and implementation should be as simple as possible for now.

I lack to find the functionality within the PayPal API's. I found the [list payments](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments/v1/#payment_list), but for me this seems more like a server to server API or?

Comment: well, you can do the server to server using the server that serves your webpage - paypal is unlikely to have an API that you can use from a webpage directly - security reasons

Comment: @JaromandaX it could be as simple as the user tries to repurchase the same thing and is getting redirected backed, that he already has purchased this and cannot purchase it a second time?

Comment: yeah - I did understand, my point was to access the Paypal API from your server rather than a clients browser

Comment: How would you verify the redirects from PayPal? Is the URL going to be the only protection? I mean, it gives you no real  security.

Comment: @frax I do not compromise security security, but I do a compromise on strenth of protecting download without payment. For new payments I just use the paypal pay button with its redirect back confirming a user did a payment. On sucessfull redirect back I replace the pay button with the download button. But this does not work for redownloading. Cookies or localstorage would be a simple solution but only work within one browser, thus I was thinking of using paypal instead.

Comment: Well, yeah, that's what I meant. The download is not protected, except for the partially hidden URLs. But after someone downloads it, they can just share the URL and anyone can use it for download, not getting through your page at all. And assuming that the return URLs would be send to PayPal in the request, it would be relatively easy to extract them and fake the redirect from PayPal to get the download button. Perhaps you are fine with that. I'm just pointing out that the protection is really just superficial.

Answer (score 0):

How do you know who the "user" is when they visit your site? Are you proposing having them log in to your site with their PayPal account? (Connect with PayPal integration?). That would be very unusual, and unsuitable for people who paid with PayPal as a guest.

So what you are proposing is somewhere between impractical and not possible.

Instead, you need to authenticate the user yourself -- provide them with a username/password to login, for example, or a unique link, though be warned such links could be shared. Then, once authenticated, check your own database as to whether they paid/subscribed or not. You need to maintain your own records.

Expecting a payment processing service to somehow do any of this for you is a misplaced expectation.

Typical implementations are to send an email with the download link, or to use a digital product delivery service such as for example e-junkie

Comment: working in the lean startup stile. I like to evaluate an idea with minimal effort. I like to avoid all the effort to build a login, save paid/subscription to database, ... . Also I think it is not untypical for modern payment services to provide APIs for logged in users to get this information or ensure they do not repay for a thing you only can purchase once. With native app stores I also get this information from the app stores. I'm not saying I would not implement all the things you wrote for a proper implementation. I fully agree if the idea works out all this is necessary.

Comment: Native app stores are a whole ecosystem. A payment processing service like PayPal provides none of that, it is just a payment service. If you need digital product delivery then write your own system or find a service provider; e-junkie is just one example